# Charging VAT on reselling foreign Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law

We are a VAT registered web design company in the UK and we're offering a Wordpress website to a new client which will include a third party plugin purchased from a US website.

My question is; when we bill our client for this plugin, do we have to charge them VAT for it?

Comment: where is the customer based?

Comment: @David Also in the UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are VAT registered in the UK, you must include VAT on *every* invoice that you send out. And unless you find there is an exemption for Wordpress plugins, which I doubt, the VAT rate will be 20%.

Comment: that is what I thought. I will pass that on to the accounts guy. A faster answer than we'd get from our accountant, thanks.